# SpelEvaluationException interpreting "access" string in ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter

Tags: nullpointerexception, oauth-2.0, spring-el, spring-security-oauth2

Any ideas on this?

From Tomcat:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1011E:(pos 8): Method call: Attempted to call method throwOnError(java.lang.Boolean) on null context object
```

Returned to Client:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to evaluate expression '#oauth2.throwOnError(#oauth2.hasScope('read') and #oauth2.hasScope('write') and #oauth2.hasAnyRole('ROLE_USER','ROLE_ADMIN'))'
    org.springframework.security.access.expression.ExpressionUtils.evaluateAsBoolean(ExpressionUtils.java:13)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter.vote(WebExpressionVoter.java:34)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter.vote(WebExpressionVoter.java:18)
    org.springframework.security.access.vote.UnanimousBased.decide(UnanimousBased.java:77)
```

I do a POST to my authorization server /oauth/token and get a token.

If I take that token and add a Authorization: Bearer  header to a GET request to the resource server, I get that error.

In my subclass of ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter, the line it blows up on is here:

```
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http
    .authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/api/**")

.access("#oauth2.hasScope('read') and #oauth2.hasScope('write') and #oauth2.hasAnyRole('ROLE_USER','ROLE_ADMIN')")

    .accessDecisionManager(accessDecisionManager())
    .anyRequest()
    .fullyAuthenticated();
```

I know that the resource server recognizes the token because if i leave it out, I get the proper error.  If I make up a fake one then I get the "invalid token" message, which is expected.   If I use the actual token Spring is jumps in and blows up on the .access()

Thanks in advance for any help.   I'm putting the code for my ResourceReserver below:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfigurer extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint oAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint;


    @Autowired
    private ResourceServerTokenServices tokenServices;

    @Autowired
    private TokenStore tokenStore;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("oauth2ResourceId")
    private String oauth2ResourceId; 

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("oauth2Realm")
    private String oauth2Realm;

    @Bean
    OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint oAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint() {
        final OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint entryPoint = new OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint();
        entryPoint.setRealmName(oauth2Realm);
        entryPoint.setTypeName("Basic");
        return entryPoint;
    }

    private AccessDecisionManager accessDecisionManager() {
        return new UnanimousBased(Arrays.<AccessDecisionVoter>asList(new ScopeVoter(),
                                                                     new AuthenticatedVoter(),
                                                                     new WebExpressionVoter()));
    }

    private AuthenticationManager getAuthenticationManager() {
        final OAuth2AuthenticationManager oAuth2AuthenticationManager = new OAuth2AuthenticationManager();
        oAuth2AuthenticationManager.setTokenServices(tokenServices);

        return oAuth2AuthenticationManager;
    }

    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/api/**")
        .access("#oauth2.hasScope('read') and #oauth2.hasScope('write') and #oauth2.hasAnyRole('ROLE_USER','ROLE_ADMIN')")
        .accessDecisionManager(accessDecisionManager())
        .anyRequest()
        .fullyAuthenticated();

        http
        .anonymous()
        .disable();

        http
        .sessionManagement()
        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.NEVER);

        http
        .logout()
        .logoutUrl("/oauth/logout")
        .logoutSuccessHandler(logoutSuccessHandler())
        .invalidateHttpSession(true);

/*        
        http
        .requiresChannel()
        .antMatchers("/oauth/api/**")
        .requiresSecure();

        http
        .portMapper()
        .http(8080)
        .mapsTo(8443);
*/  

    }


    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) throws Exception {
        resources
        .authenticationManager(getAuthenticationManager())
        .tokenServices(tokenServices)
        .tokenStore(tokenStore)
        .resourceId(oauth2ResourceId);
    }

    private LogoutSuccessHandler logoutSuccessHandler() {
        return new OAuth2SuccessLogoutHandler(tokenStore);
    }

    static final class OAuth2SuccessLogoutHandler implements LogoutSuccessHandler {

        private final TokenStore tokenStore;

        public OAuth2SuccessLogoutHandler(final TokenStore tokenStore) {
            this.tokenStore = tokenStore;
        }

        @Override
        public void onLogoutSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
               request.toString();
        }


    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `hasAnyRole()` method is not OAuth2 related and therefore is not on the `#oauth2` variable (it's on the root so you don't need to qualify it).

Comment: Ah yes good point.   I swapped it to just hasAnyRole.   It's still blowing up with the same null exception.   It couldn't be that the oauth2 parser is not being accessed somehow could it?    The Spring docs claim when @EnableResourceServer is used then the oauth2 expression handler will be registered by default?     I'm really pretty stuck on this.    Trying to debug through some of the Spring code to try to engineer what is going on.    Thanks again for any help.

Comment: Yes, your `WebExpressionVoter` doesn't have the OAuth2 expression handler. You shouldn't really need that (just use the default access decision handler).

Comment: Success!    Yes we nuked the custom accessDecisionManager (that was copied from an example somewhere).     That allows the default oauth2 expression handler to work.     That combined with your note on removing #oauth2 from hasAnyRoles has solved the issues we were having.   Thank you for the help!